# Whose costume is Richard "Rip" Hunter holding?

Tags: dc, rip-hunter, booster-gold

**[Rip Hunter, Time Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Hunter)** of the DC Universe is making a comeback. And he is getting some help. The costume on the right, I recognize as **[Booster Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booster_Gold)**.

- **Whose costume is that on the left?**
- A name and a brief history or a link would be nice.

[image]

Comment: If *you* don't know, who will?

Comment: There's only one man who can answer this, and his name is @Richard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the costume of **Supernova**, who has been two different people so far.

Booster Gold used the identity Supernova, with that costume, during *52*. He had recently faked his own death, and used this alternate identity to go back in time and try to repair his malfunctioning Skeets.

[image]

After Supernova revealed himself to be Booster Gold, Rip Hunter would give that identity, and a very similar suit, to Daniel Carter, an ancestor of Booster Gold (Michael Jon Carter) who lived in the 21st Century. Like Booster Gold, this Supernova also has no super-human abilities of his own, but gets them from the suit (which was created by Rip Hunter).

Until now, Daniel Carter's appearances seem limited to *Booster Gold* volume 2, and he hasn't appeared in any comic since Flashpoint.

[image]

Since Rip is talking to someone named Daniel about the "Carter legacy" I suspect the suit is meant for him in this case.